# Primefaces Editor - removeFormat bug?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using PF 5.1.

When I try to add the `removeFormat` control in my code the `p:editor` doesn't appear:

```
<p:editor value="..." controls="bold italic ... removeFormat" width="600"/>
```

But when I omit the `removeFormat` it works just fine.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://speakerdeck.com/cagataycivici/primefaces-user-guide-5-dot-3?slide=200) it should be a `removeFormat` parameter (camelCased), but it worked for me only written as `removeformat`.

Comment: Using the org.primefaces version 5.3 dependency.